# Keep a specific "using" statement when cleaning up code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, code-cleanup, using-directives

I am a huge fan of keyboard shortcuts. I am especially fond of `Remove and Sort Usings` in Visual Studio. Until now, I had no reason to question the use of such a command. I recently discovered that a `using` statement existed in several files but was not actually used at all in the files. I had no problems letting the command wipe it from my view until I tried to update service reference and discovered that some properties could not be serialized. `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` would allow the classes in question to be reflected with whatever magic was required to update the service reference. Having added this line back into several classes, teaching several people I work with shortcuts to help keep their code clean, and general forgetfulness, I can see this line being removed at some point in the future and someone new wondering why things won't serialize anymore.

Is there an attribute to attach to this statement that can keep it from being removed by auto-formatting techniques?

**EDIT**

My mistake in the description. The service reference could not be updated because the service itself could not start. When attempting to start it, and error in the Event Viewer stated that the service could not be started due to new properties of the class not being serializable. The class being the first one to attempt serialization - fix or remove the code in question and the next class would appear in the next error log. I discovered, by examining other classes, that the difference between those not being serializable and one being serializable was the classes that couldn't were missing the line: `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`

Comment: I think something else caused your problem - adding a using statement does not magically add any capabilities - it just lets you use classes in that namespace without having to type out the namespace.  If something used it and you removed it, the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: (continuing from what D Stanley said...) Or if it did compile, it would be using a different class for something. Unless a bug exists in VS, this won't happen, because that means the `using` actually was in use.

Comment: Find out which class is being referenced when you have the `using System.Runtime.Serialization` in place. Then explicitly qualify those classes. I.E., if the class is specified as "X", then make it "`System.Runtime.Serialization.X`". Then remove the `using System.Runtime.Serialization`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - None. I can remove that statement and use the dll with any other project. I can also remove that statement and use the dll in the service if there are no other changes. I can remove the statement and use the dll in the service but no longer update the service reference.

Comment: What do you mean, "none". If removing the `using` changes the meaning of the program (like, being able to serialize the class, then not being able to serialize the class), then it implies that there has been a change in a type, from one that can be serialized to one which cannot be serialized.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - None as in no uses of Serialization or anything in that namespace. The classes I added it to are database objects (Domain Objects as I understand it); they contain properties with simple `{get;set;}` and the types, no other code in them - ex.         `public virtual String Name { get; set; }`.

Comment: I'm not saying that you deliberately use serialization. I'm saying that there is some declaration whose meaning changes when you add the `using`. In particular, some of the "new properties" have a type which is not serializable. I suspect you'll find that type is in the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace when you have the `using`, but that the same property is in a different namespace when you remove the `using`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - If a property type is listed in separate referenced Namespaces, wouldn't the compiler throw an error when trying to compile types without the full Namespace listed? I have using `using System.Collections.Generic;` and a property of type List<> instead of `System.Collections.Generic.List<>`. The few occasions when I come across a property type that exists in multiple namespaces, the compiler won't do anything until I resolve that issue.

Comment: @scott.smart: that's what I was thinking as well, but don't see how else changing the `using` could change whether or not the type was serializable.